Ages of Xander, Alice, Bob, and Carol
I need help with quadratics and derivatives for this problem:
Problem:
Xander, Alice, Bob, and Carol all have unknown ages. We are told that if we multiply the age of Alice by the square of the age of Xander, then add to that the product of Bob and Xander's ages, we obtain the age of Carol.  I must solve for the age of Xander in terms of the ages Alice, Bob, and Carol. Using calculus, I must describe how the rate of change of Xander's age depends on Bob's age.
Here is my work: Define
\begin{align}
\partial &= \mbox{Xander age} \\
\delta &= \mbox{Alice age}\\
\eth &= \mbox{Bob age} \\
d &= \mbox{Carl age}
\end{align}
I obtain the equation
$$ \delta(\partial)^2 + \eth\partial = d$$
and the quadratic formula gives
$$ \partial = \frac{-\eth \pm \sqrt{\eth^2+4\delta d}}{2\delta}$$
Question: Is this a reasonable approach? Can someone help me take a partial derivative of the right-hand-side with respect to the age of Bob?

$\frac{\partial \partial}{\partial \eth}=-\frac{1}{2\delta}\pm \frac{\eth}{2\delta \sqrt{\eth^2+4\delta d}}$

Do those people age with different rates?

@peterwhy : Good question. We are not told whether or not they are moving at different velocities. It is possible that one or more are moving near light speed.

@Morten : Impressive!

In view of Peter's comment, let us assume the age relationship holds locally in some open time interval. Assume they are traveling in the same straight line with instantaneous speeds of Xander, Alice, Bob, Carol at the time of interest given by $\Delta_\partial$, $\Delta_\delta$, $\Delta_\eth$, $\Delta_d$, respectively. I am adding a tag on physics.

$\partial = 43$.

Another approach would be to note the coincidental first character of the names, and realize that you have $~\displaystyle Ax^2 + Bx - C = 0.$

@user2661923 : That may work but your change in notation may be confusing to some people. =)

I think that $x$, $A$, $B$, and $C$ is both more obvious and clearer.  Four variants of $d$ is rather weird and confusing.

I very much have to agree with the other commenters.  The characters are named Xander ($x$), Alice ($a$), Bob ($b$), and Carol ($c$).  These names are screaming for the variable names indicated here.

@XanderHenderson : Indeed! I had assumed everyone would interpret my question the same way that people have currently interpreted your $\partial = 43$ comment (+1). However, you seem to have missed the answer to life the universe and everything by a year. I typed up my question after answering a previous question where the OP formulated a 2-sentence problem that used both $\omega$ and $w$. Peter greatly expanded the scope of my question. I had assumed taking partial derivatives in my formulation would be impossible, but Morten was undeterred!

@badjohn : Given your suggestion aligns with that of other users, I see it may be better to change the names of the people in my problem to $\partial$ander, $\delta$lice, $\eth$ob, $d$arol.

@Michael Indeed, that will solve the problem nicely.  My apologies for the breakdown in my sense of humour.
